# c# adding row to datatable which has an auto increment column

Tags: c#, datatable, auto-increment

I've a datatable, with column A, B, C. I've set column A's "is identity" property to true, but I can't add any row to the table now.

The code I'm trying is this:

```
dsA.dtA row = dsA.dtA.NewdtARow();

row.B = 1;
row.C = 2;

dsA.dtA.Rows.Add(row);
```

I'm getting NoNullAllowedException, but I don't understand why. Column A is PK as well. If I tried to set row.A = 5 (or any similiar) I'll get an error when I try to update the datatable saying "cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when identity_insert is set to off"

How can I solve this issue? It's frustrating.

Comment: I have already answered it but it would be great it you can put a break point on the line dts.rows.add(row) and check it out that does row.A is carrying.

Comment: You may want to check if IDENTITY_INSERT is ON or OFF for your table.

Comment: ColumnModel.IsIdentity (EF) and DataColumn.AutoIncrement (ADO Datatable) are two different things in two different frameworks.

IsIdentity is saying the database will provide the value. 

AutoIncrement is saying the datatable object will provide the value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this way. Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumn_AutoIncrement)

```
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.AutoIncrement = true;
column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;

// Add the column to a new DataTable.
DataTable table = new DataTable("table");
table.Columns.Add(column);

DataRow oRow = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.Add(oRow);
```

Comment: @John also see this [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.autoincrement.aspx)

Comment: But what if I already have the datatable with an existing column that has autoincrement? I just simply want to add a row to that table, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the these two:

1. Set field values:

   ```
   row.A = null;
   row.B = 1;
   row.C = 3;
   ```
2. Add row to `DataTable`:

   ```
   dtA.Rows.Add(null,1,2);
   ```

They are both the same just try any of them and it should get you going. Also remember that whenever you want to make a column auto-increment in `DataTable` then you have to insert null into it.

Comment: Both method fail. The first one won't even compile, saying cannot convert null to int. Second one simply just fails like my own method with NoNullAllowedException.

Comment: DataTable dt = new DataTable();            dt.Columns.Add("A",System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")).AutoIncrement = true;dt.Columns.Add("B");
 dt.Rows.Add(null, "abc"); 
 dt.Rows.Add(null, "xyz"); I checked this and it worked in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Open the designer of the dataset xsd file and set the AutoIncrement, AutoIncrementSeed and AutoIncrementStep property of the column A in datatable for an existing column.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do it is

```
public void AppendtodtA(int num1, doubledouble1, string string1)
{
    object[] RowArray = new object[] {null,(int)num1, (double) doubledouble1, (string) string1}
    DataRow CurrentRow = dtA.NewRow();
    CurrentRow.ItemArray = RowArray;
    dtA.Rows.Add(CurrentRow);
}
```

use `ItemArray` property and leave a `null` in the place of the autoincremented column

```
AppendtodtA(MyNumber,MyDouble,MyString);
```

Then just call the method with your variables.